# Looking for an ipv4 over ipv6 tunnel

Tags: networking, ipv6, tunnel

So my internet has half died. Something got broken on the IPv4 side so all we have is IPv6. This has happened before as well. (Not gonna get into the headaches of customer support here.)

I have seen mentions of 4in6 tunnels but other than them existing in theory I cannot find anything. Most are setup to allow the opposite where you tunnel IPv6 over IPv4 but in my current case I have no ipv4 at all.

If there is a quick and easy way to do so on say a digital ocean droplet I am up for that as well but Im not too great with linux. Open to most ways of doing this.

Comment: You'll get more results if searching for instructions on setting up a "VPN", I guess. Especially as most VPN tutorials already focus on carrying IPv4 traffic anyway.

Comment: In theory but the ones I could find were all doing the vpn over ipv4. (Im not too in trouble if I can't do this as I do have unlimited tethering on my cell phone but it runs around 130 ping which is not really viable for many things.)

Comment: The *outer* protocol isn't really a problem – most VPN software is automatically capable of running over both v4 and v6, with no special setup needed.